# Outlook 2013 does not connect to Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, outlook, cas

I installed an Exchange2013-Server on Windows2012. The Windows2012 server also acts as domain controller - just everything is on this machine.

The server has an internal FQDN (machine.test.internaldomain.local). I also configured an subdomain that points to a dyndns-address. The dyndns client is a router that is configured to pass through every SSL-request to the Exchange2013 server.

I created some test user with the following results:
- Receiving mails works.
- Sending mails via OWA works.
- Connecting my Windows Phone via Exchange connector works.

Configuring Outlook 2013 (using the subdomain as the server address) within my internal network does not work. I got a message that says that the folder group cannot be opened and I have to establish a connection with the Exchange2013 server. Maybe the problem ist, that Outlook replaced the subdomain with the internal FQDN from the server. When I execute:

Get-MailboxDatabase | fl name,RpcClientAccessServer

it prints out the internal FQDN. But this is not, what I want. How can I handle this?

Thanks,
Holger

Comment: Why aren't you using autodiscover?

Comment: And have you correctly configured your internal/external URI/URLs?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that you configured Outlook to connect to test.internaldomain.local rather than machine.test.internaldomain.local?

Comment: I configured Outlook to connect to external.mydomain.com. But after entering my mailbox credentials the server name is replaced by machine.test.internaldomain.local

Comment: Assuming that you're using Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTPS) that sounds right to me. external.mydomain.com is the RPC proxy server that then connects you to the CAS server. Both can be one and the same. external.mydomain.com is the "external" name and  machine.test.internaldomain.local is the "internal" name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTPS) that sounds right to me. external.mydomain.com is the RPC proxy server that then connects you to the CAS server. Both can be one and the same. external.mydomain.com is the "external" name and machine.test.internaldomain.local is the "internal" name. Here are some screenshots of my Outlook settings. Note that the server listed in both screenshots is the same server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: joeqwerty, entering a proxy server brought me a step closer to the solution, I think. I entered the external FQDN into the "proxy server" field. When I start Outlook, it complains about an insecure certificate (the cert was issued for the host with the internal FQDN, not the external). Have I to recreate a new certificate that was issued by the external URL?

Comment: Outlook connects to the proxy server so you need a certificate that matches the FQDN of the proxy server. What you probably want is a UC/SAN certificate that contains the external and the internal names.